# sql query about given date if not existing, give latest date

Tags: sql, subquery, max

I have this table.

InformationValues(attr , dateOfValue, price)

Table Content:

[image]

I need to select all attr with the same date if it  doesn't exist the latest date should be selected.

For example with `TO_DATE('01-jan-19')`

Solution table should look like this:

[image]

My sql query so far:

```
select iv.attr , price, dateofvalue from informationvalues iv where
 dateofvalue = (select max(dateofvalue) from informationvalues where attr = iv.attr) or
 dateofvalue = TO_DATE('01-jan-19');
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`row_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) analytic function:

```
select t.attr, t.dateOfValue, t.price
from ( 
  select i.*,
    row_number() over (
      partition by attr 
      order by case when dateOfValue = to_date('01-jan-19') then 1 else 2 end, dateOfValue desc
    ) rn
  from InformationValues i
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3476941f9c92a87ad26f94e2bc2902be).
Results:

```
> ATTR           | DATEOFVALUE | PRICE
> :------------- | :---------- | ----:
> age            | 01-JAN-19   |     2
> electronics    | 01-JAN-19   |   0.5
> gender         | 01-JAN-19   |     3
> hobbies        | 01-JAN-19   |   0.5
> homeAddress    | 01-JAN-20   |     7
> maritalStatus  | 01-NOV-18   |     1
> mobilePhone    | 01-JAN-19   |     5
> musicTaste     | 01-JUL-19   |   0.1
> socialContacts | 01-JAN-19   |     1
```

Comment: How would this look like in PL/SQL if I would use a cursor and then outputline the date I want and if not existing the latest one ?

Comment: This is sql code that answers your question. If you have another requirement you can ask a new question where you explain what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select * from (
select attr, price, dateofvalue,
row_number() over (partition by attr order by dateofvalue desc) rn from informationvalues
) i where dateofvalue = date'2019-01-01'
or (rn = 1 and not exists (select 1 from informationvalues iv where iv.attr = i.attr and dateofvalue = date'2019-01-01') )
```

Comment: If the date '2019-01-01' doesn't exist the latest date should be selected. Which is not the case for "attr" 'homeadress'

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by the question

if you mean, the data chosen is crossed out, 
try this one:

```
Select  a.attr, Min(dateofvalue) dateofvalue_MIN, Max(dateofvalue) dateofvalue_MAX, price
From #TableName a
Inner Join (
    Select attr
    From #TableName
    Group By attr
    Having Count(1) > 1
    ) b On b.attr = a.attr
Group By a.attr, price
```

if you mean, the data chosen is not crossed out,
try this one:

```
Select  a.attr, Min(dateofvalue) dateofvalue_MIN, Max(dateofvalue) dateofvalue_MAX, price
From #TableName a
Group By a.attr, price
```

Thx